# how to conditionally create aws_eip and aws_eip_association?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to be able to conditionally create an EIP and associate it to an instance:

```
resource "aws_eip" "gateway" {
  vpc = true

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project_id}-gateway"
    Project = "${var.project_id}"
    user = "${var.user}"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc_gateway" {
  instance_id   = aws_instance.gateway.id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.gateway.id
}

resource "aws_instance" "gateway" {
...
}
```

Unfortunately, `aws_eip` and `aws_eip_association` don't appear to support the `count` attribute, so I'm not clear if this is even possible?

Any ideas?

Comment: All resources support count, why do you think aws_eip/aws_eip_association do not?

Comment: `count` is a [meta-argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#meta-arguments), so it won't appear in the documentation for `aws_eip`.

Comment: Is this related? https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/4944

Comment: @Rome_Leader - if you add your comment as an answer, I'd gladly accept it and upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, count is supported by all Terraform primitive resources. Example for aws_eip below:

```
resource "aws_eip" "eip" {
  instance   = "${element(aws_instance.manager.*.id,count.index)}"
  count = "${var.eip_count}"
  vpc = true

}
```